# Any restrictions for branching within a conditional statement in a batch file?

Tags: loops, batch-file, conditional-statements, goto

This code works as expected:

```
  :loop 
    set /p choice="Your choice (y/n)"
    echo "recorded choice is %choice%"
    goto loop
```

leads to:

```
Your choice (y/n)n
"recorded choice is n"
Your choice (y/n)n
"recorded choice is n"
...
```

but this code doesn't:

```
if 1==1 (
  :loop 
    set /p choice="Your choice (y/n)"
    echo "recorded choice is %choice%"
    goto loop
)
```

The first iteration doesn't set choice as expected:

```
Your choice (y/n)n
"recorded choice is "
Your choice (y/n)n
"recorded choice is n"
Your choice (y/n)n
```

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

Use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` for more on it, do `setlocal /?` from cmdline.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if 1==1 (
  :loop 
    set /p choice="Your choice (y/n)"
    echo "recorded choice is !choice!"
    goto loop
)
endlocal
```